# Include in bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

[image: This is how it looks when everything is in one file]
index.php file

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="head">
    <?php include_once("menu.php"); ?>
</div>
```

menu.php file

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#menu">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Silverado</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="movies.php">Movies</a></li>
         <li class="active"><a href="price.php">Price List</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

This is my code for displaying menu in webpage using bootstrap. This works fine. But i want to keep this bit of code in different file and include it in my webpage using include_once tag of php. If I put this code in different file and include it in my webpage it doesnt display the menu at all if i run my index.php page. Please help!

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: Please let us know what you tried, and be a bit clearer on what exactly you mean with "it does not work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... The PHP in your `index.php` should look like this :

```
include_once ('index.php');
```

And put the `head` elements in your `index.php`.

Be sure `PHP` is working. Put this somewhere :

```
<?php echo "PHP is working !"; ?>
```

Here is what you should have :

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include_once ("menu.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

menu.php :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#menu">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Silverado</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="movies.php">Movies</a></li>
         <li class="active"><a href="price.php">Price List</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Actually this isnt true.. If they are included in the parent it will work just fine.

Comment: `i want to keep this bit of code in different file and include it` He want to add it in an other page. One is working, but not the other.

Comment: correct.. so if its working in 1 then using an `include_once` should not change the css // js .. .They are not moving anywhere. So they will STILL be loaded.

Comment: I entirely changed my answer :D

Comment: I did this. I have kept the edited code. It still doesnt display the menu.

Comment: Hmm... I will try this in an hour, but that's weird. Are your sure the paths to the bootstrap files are correct

Comment: Yes they are completely correct! When i keep them in one single file they work fine which conclude that the paths are perfectly fine. But when i separate them in two different files the menu disappears completely!

Comment: Wait... Do you even have a server or a local server ? I copied/pasted the code in my answer, and it's woring : seblor.fr/stackoverflow/Saransh . Answer edited.

Comment: No problem. (I deleted the demo)